# How to show/hide images using javascript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html page showing pictures of different countries and 5 li elements with ids that represent 4 countries, the 5th li tag make all images to show. By clicking on one li tag (it represent curtain country) only the pictures of that country remains and the others disappear. But what i have to do is to make my javascript code with objects. I am extremely new to JS and I have no clue how to do it :(

Here is my JS code:

```
(function() {
    document.getElementById('all').addEventListener('click', showAll);
    document.getElementById('italy').addEventListener('click', showItaly);
    document.getElementById('france').addEventListener('click', showFrance);
    document.getElementById('croatia').addEventListener('click', showCroatia);
    document.getElementById('montenegro').addEventListener('click', showMontenegro);

    var italyCities = document.getElementsByClassName('italyCities');
    var franceCities = document.getElementsByClassName('franceCities');
    var croatiaCities = document.getElementsByClassName('croatiaCities');
    var montenegroCities = document.getElementsByClassName('montenegroCities');

    // onclick show all cities
    function showAll() {
        for (let i = 0; i < italyCities.length; i++) {
            italyCities[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
            franceCities[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
            croatiaCities[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
            montenegroCities[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
    }

    // onclick show only italian cities
    function showItaly() {
        for (let i = 0; i < italyCities.length; i++) {
            franceCities[i].style.display = 'none';
            croatiaCities[i].style.display = 'none';
            montenegroCities[i].style.display = 'none';
            italyCities[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
    }

    // onclick show only french cities
    function showFrance() {
        for (let i = 0; i < franceCities.length; i++) {
            italyCities[i].style.display = 'none';
            croatiaCities[i].style.display = 'none';
            montenegroCities[i].style.display = 'none';
            franceCities[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
    }

    // onclick show only croatian cities
    function showCroatia() {
        for (let i = 0; i < croatiaCities.length; i++) {
            italyCities[i].style.display = 'none';
            franceCities[i].style.display = 'none';
            montenegroCities[i].style.display = 'none';
            croatiaCities[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
    }

    // onclick show only montenegro cities
    function showMontenegro() {
        for (let i = 0; i < montenegroCities.length; i++) {
            italyCities[i].style.display = 'none';
            franceCities[i].style.display = 'none';
            croatiaCities[i].style.display = 'none';
            montenegroCities[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: *But what i have to do is to make my javascript code with objects.* You'll need to be more specific. What aspect of your code should use objects? Also, there is no need for all those separate functions that essentially do the same thing. Just make one function that takes the country as an argument and then it operates on that argument.

Comment: Do you have errors ?

Comment: No, this code work correct. But I have to do it with objects.

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I don't see any.

Comment: Oh, excuse me, I forgot to mention that the code can be in jQuery. It's not necessary to be in vanilla js

Comment: As I mentioned above, you have so much redundant code. Please see this Fiddle that I created to show a working solution that removes all that clutter. It doesn't use objects (which is why I'm posting it as a comment), but the use of objects is not obvious in this problem. https://jsfiddle.net/1ryp682z/24/

Comment: Thank you very much, this was pretty helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're over-complicating things for yourself. Instead of having a function  for each place that just changes the inline-style of the one you want to show and hides the rest you could do this all with one function...

If you were to use a general class for all of the cities, say **.city** you could toggle a hide/show class across all of them at once.

**CSS**

```
.hide {
    display:none;
}
.show {
    display:block;
}
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {   
            $(".city").addClass('hide'); 
            $("li:first-child").click(function() { 
               $(".city").removeClass('show'); 
               $(".city:nth-child(2)").addClass('show');
            });
            $("li:nth-child(2)").click(function() { 
              $(".city").removeClass('show'); 
              $(".city:nth-child(3)").addClass('show');
            });
            $("li:nth-child(3)").click(function() { 
              $(".city").removeClass('show'); 
              $(".city:nth-child(4)").addClass('show');
            });
            $("li:last-child").click(function() { 
              $(".city").addClass('show');        
           });
});
```

**Update**

For anyone who comes across this and isn't planning on using objects - here is a fiddle showing the principle of the question working.

https://jsfiddle.net/shzq8fd5/10/

**Original Code Answer**

CSS

```
.show {
     display:block;
 }
 .hide {
     display:none;
 }
```

Individual City Function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
      $(".city").addClass('hide');    
      $(".city").click(function() {
          $(".city").removeClass('show'); 
          $(this).addClass('show');
      });
});
```

Show all City Function

```
 $(document).ready(function() {       
      $(".city").click(function() {              
          $(".city").addClass('show');             
      });
});
```

Comment: This is really optimized code, thank you so much! I will use it! The problem is that I have a task doing this with objects or this is it ? Sorry for the stupid questions but I am really new to this. I though objects include { key: value }

Comment: Ahh Ic! No disrespect intended I just thought you were doing objects by choice, if you have to use objects then that's a different story!

Comment: @XxXtraCookie You have to tell us what aspect of your code should use objects. That is not apparent from your question. I could possibly see the cities being stored in arrays and the HTML lists being created from those arrays, but the use of objects is not obvious with this problem.

Comment: @HisPowerLevelIsOver900 what was you previous answer ? It was going to be more useful for me, thank in advance.

Comment: @XxXtraCookie will post it again for you!

Comment: @XxXtraCookie original response is now added at the bottom

Comment: @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000 Thank you very much ^.^